# How to detect if a property is numeric type in haxe?

Tags: haxe

I need to detect if a property of an object is numeric or not ( Int or Float )
What I have is the object reference, and property name as string

Here is my implementation, `compoent` is the object reference, but it didn't work

```
public function IsNumeric():Bool
    {
        if (Std.is(Type.typeof(Reflect.getProperty(compoent, propertyName)), Int)) return true;
        if (Std.is(Type.typeof(Reflect.getProperty(compoent, propertyName)), Float)) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Any one can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit simpler than what you're trying: `Std.is( value, type )`

```
class Test {
  static function main(){
    js.Lib.alert( Std.is("string", Int) );
    js.Lib.alert( Std.is(0, Int) );
    js.Lib.alert( Std.is(0.3, Int) );
    js.Lib.alert( Std.is("string", Float) );
    js.Lib.alert( Std.is(0, Float) );
    js.Lib.alert( Std.is(0.3, Float) );
  }
}
```

See http://try.haxe.org/#6A9Bd